# SQLite не реагирует на что-либо

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Недавно начал делать программу и столкнулся с одной проблемой: sqlite вообще ни на что не реагирует. Даже при полностью неправильном синтаксисе он не выдает никаких Exception, в общем никаких признаков жизни

```
import discord
import datetime
import sqlite3

from discord.ext import commands
from settings import token, question_channel

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents, case_insensitive=True, help_command=None)

db = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
c = db.cursor()


@bot.command()
async def помощь(message: discord.Message, *, question = None):
    if question is None:
        return await message.reply("Неправильное использование команды! Верное использование:\n**/помощь вопрос**")

    time = datetime.datetime.now()

    question_ch = bot.get_channel(question_channel)
    
    reportik = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 255, 0),
     color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 255, 0),
     title='Поступил вопрос!',
     type='article',
     description=f'Автор: {message.author.mention}\nВопрос: {question}\n\nВремя поступления вопроса: **{time}**')
    
    reportik.set_author(name=message.author.display_name, icon_url=message.author.avatar)
    await question_ch.send(embed=reportik)

    c.execute(f"INSERT INTO questions(message_id, author_id, isAnswered, question) VALUES('{message.id}', '{message.author.id}', '0', '{question}')")
    print('+')
    db.commit()

    return await message.reply('Ваш вопрос успешно отправлен!')

bot.run(str(token))
```

Comment: В показанном здесь коде весь синтаксис правильный и реагировать не на что. Приведите [mcve], демонстрирующий проблему (то есть отсутствие Exception там, где он по-вашему должен быть)

Comment: изменил свой вопрос

Comment: Если не придираться к sql-инъекции, то в показанном коде я не вижу чего-то синтаксически неправильного. Почему вы решили, что где-то должен быть какой-то Exception?

Comment: скорее всего, потому что он не сохраняет данные. Все таблицы проверил, код тоже, но почему-то не реагирует на данный запрос, а если точнее, то на этом запросе(c.execute(INSERT INTO questions) он "зависает" и не делает дальнейших действий

Comment: Под «не делает дальнейших действий» вы имеете в виду, что `print('+')` тоже не печатается?

Comment: так оно и есть, специально добавил его для проверки

Comment: Вы случайно не обращаетесь к той же самой базе из какого-нибудь другого скрипта?

Comment: Прошу прощения за столь долгий ответ, нет, не обращаюсь

Comment: А перед `execute` не пробовали `print` ставить, может до него и не доходит ход?

Comment: Пробовал даже убирать execute, без него все работает

Comment: У вас получилось решить эту проблему?